# What I need to use: aggregation or composition in TDD?

Tags: php, mocking, tdd, phpunit

I'm using TDD. I need to use raw SQL queries in my system. TDD suggests that I need to test only business logic (all tests of database, mail sending or file system is a integration tests). So, I place my SQL code in a separated class which I want to mock. Here is a code:

```
// Creating shipping method data provider mock
$shippingMethodDataProviderMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\ordersmanager\Model\Order\ShippingMethod\ShippingMethodDataProvider')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

// Getting shipping method instance
$emsShippingMethod = ShippingMethodFactory::getShippingMethod('ems', $shippingMethodDataProviderMock);
```

But I don't want to pass a `ShippingMethodProvider` instance to the `ShippingMethodFactory` in client code.

I can use a composition instead of aggregation: creating a `ShippingMethodProvider` in a `ShippingMethodFactory` and pass it to `ShippingMethod` constructor. But in that case I can't mock `ShippingMethodProvider` because it isolated from client code.

I can create a wrapper for `ShippingMethodFactory` that will not be unit-tested but will create a pleasant API like this:

```
$emsShippingMethod = ShippingMethodFactory::getShippingMethod('ems');
```

But this wrapper will not be tested.

What is a better way to test this and have a good API?

Comment: just create Mocks for the immediate collaborators of the Subject Under Test inside your TestCase